# How to solve “Cannot build without libcrypto (OpenSSL)”?

Tags: linux, openssl, libcrypto

I use commands as below to build and install xar-1.5.2, but libssl1.0-dev can’t be installed, I use libssl-dev instead of it.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libxml2-dev libssl1.0-dev zlib1g-dev
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/xar/xar-1.5.2.tar.gz
tar -zxvf xar-1.5.2.tar.gz
cd xar-1.5.2
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

when I run `./configure`, I got error at last, the configure is failed.

```
checking for OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers in -lcrypto... no
configure: error: Cannot build without libcrypto (OpenSSL)
```

There is openssl on my antix 22, what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: ever figured out?